# Invert motor rotation depending on a potentiometer

Tags: c, arduino

How the direction of rotation of a motor changes, if I increase or decrease the value of the potentiometer when the simulation is in progress?

```
const int POT_ANEMOMETER = A4;

void setup() {
    pinMode(A3, INPUT_PULLUP); // Bouton Mode Automatique
    pinMode(POT_ANEMOMETER, INPUT_PULLUP); // Pin POT_ANEMOMETER
    pinMode(0, OUTPUT); // Sortie Moteur Sens Antihoraire
    pinMode(1, OUTPUT); // Sortie Moteur Sens Horaire
}

void loop() {
    float POT_ANEMOMETER = analogRead(A4);
    float V1 = (POT_ANEMOMETER / 205);

    while (digitalRead(A3) == 0) {
        for (V1 = 0, V1 < 5, V1++) {
            if (V1 >= 1.5) {
                digitalWrite(0, 0); digitalWrite(1, 1); // Sens Horaire
            } else {
                digitalWrite(0, 1); digitalWrite(1, 0); // Sens Antihoraire
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with C?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  I recommend editing your question to format the code properly.  One way to do that is to indent the whole thing with 4 spaces.  Or you can just put three backticks on their own line before the start of your code and after the end.  Also, could you provide way more details about your problem?

Comment: Presumably this is [`arduino`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino) related? I've cleaned up your code snippet, and in doing so added a missing `}` to the end (assuming it got lost in a copy-paste related accident). Additionally, `for (V1 = 0, V1 < 5, V1++)` -- you probably want semicolons, not commas.

Comment: The potentiometer is likely setting a PWM duty-cycle that is used to control the motor speed. The actual potentiometer likely sets the value when the current is "on" over the course of a frequency cycle. (lower-value -- the longer the current is "on" -- the greater the duty-cycle). This can appear to have an inverse relationship (lower-value -- greater duty-cycle), etc..

Comment: Please, try to be synthetic when redaction a question title and do not put the whole question in the title.